# Linq Query with distinct

Tags: linq, distinct

how can I write the same query using LINQ

```
SELECT distinct Subdivision
FROM [REFINED_DB].[Brokerage_Casualty].[Retention_Model_Predictions_DS_Manual]
```

Comment: A search for "linq + distinct" would surely have provided you with your answer, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Retention_Model_Predictions_DS_Manual.Select(x => x.Subdivision).Distinct()
```